# F# type definition syntax

Tags: f#

I'm working on the '99 problems of F#', and saw the following definition of `NestedList`:

```
type 'a NestedList = List of 'a NestedList list | Elem of 'a
```

I'm a little confused by the syntax here, as normally there is only a type name after the `type`. Can someone clarify it? Thanks!

Comment: What are those 99 problems?

Comment: @vtortola http://www.fssnip.net/an pretty well designed problems

Comment: Nice, I am learning fsharp myself, good resource!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [discriminated union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx) in a condensed syntax. You can also write it as:

```ml
type 'a NestedList =
    | List of 'a NestedList list
    | Elem of 'a
```

or

```ml
type NestedList<'a> =
    | List of NestedList<'a> list
    | Elem of 'a
```

This is using generics, where the type itself is taking another type as an argument.

Comment: One more way to write the first case: `List of list<NestedList<'a>>`.

Comment: Or `List of list<'a NestedList>`, if you like to mix things up. Don't, though; the space notation is generally only used for the built-in types that come from OCaml, such as `'a list` and `'a option`. `'a array` too, although we tend to prefer C#-style `'a[]`.

Answer (score 3):

F# has two ways of specifying a generic type:

- C#/.NET style - `SomeType<'a, 'b>`
- OCaml/ML style - `('a * 'b) SomeType`

Those are really two ways of saying the same thing and can be used interchangeably. Which one to use is a matter of preference and code standards. Usually people use OCaml style for basic F# types like list, array or option, and C# style for user-defined and BCL ones.

Comment: I just found this question after encountering the syntax in some blog post. Your answer is the one that helped me understand the syntax, but currently ('a * 'b) is not accepted by the F# compiler. ('a , 'b) seems to be the correct syntax. Did it change at some point?

Comment: @GrumpyRodriguez: It most certainly did not change, it would be a very weird kind of change for F# to make.  You use commas for tuple values, but `*` for tuple types, eg. `let tup : (int * string option) = (42, Some "answer")`. If you find something else to be true, ask a separate question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63198415/what-is-the-syntax-for-ocaml-style-generic-type-parameters-in-f

Answer (score 2):

So this is a definition of a generic discriminated union with generic type `'a`.

The key idea is that each element has the type `'a`.