# What is the syntax for OCaml style generic type parameters in F#?

Tags: generics, f#, ocaml

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26571378/11101800), F# supports OCaml style type parameters. The example in the question is:

```
type 'a NestedList = List of 'a NestedList list | Elem of 'a
```

However, I could not find this syntax documented anywhere in the F# documentation and moreover, I cannot get the F# compiler accept the syntax in the answer I gave the link to.
This attempt to use multiple parameters are not accepted by the compiler:

```
type ('a * 'b) SomeType = ('a * 'b)
```

This however, works:

```
type ('a , 'b) SomeType = ('a * 'b)
let x:SomeType<int,int> = (4,5)
```

Based on the type annotation Rider displays above x, I'm assuming this is the accepted syntax, but I'd like to know where this is documented and if I did get it right.
[image: Rider screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. The answer you link to is wrong. `type ('a * 'b) someType` is not valid in OCaml either. Multiple type parameters should be separated by comma there as well: `type ('a, 'b) someType`.

The F# language, including its syntax, is specified in [The F# Language Specification](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/). See in particular chapter 5 (in the 4.1 specification) for the syntax of types and chapter 8 for type definitions.